# How to list names of all pods serving traffic behind a service in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to list names of all pods which are actually serving traffic behind a kubernetes service.My question is how to achieve this by executing a single kubectl command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command worked

```
kubectl get ep servicename -o=jsonpath='{.subsets[*].addresses[*].ip}' | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I % kubectl get pods -o=name --field-selector=status.podIP=%
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've noticed that this query doesn't list running pods that are associated with service during rolling deployment

Answer (score 27):

There are two ways to list the pods behind a service.

**The easier way but with two commands**

Find the selector by running the below command

```
kubectl get services -o=wide
```

Output:

```
NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
hello-world-service   ClusterIP   172.21.xxx.xx   <none>        80/TCP    13m   run=nginx
```

Pass the selector to the command below

```
kubectl get pods --selector=run=nginx -o=name
```

To see the exact pod names without `pod/`

```
kubectl get pods --selector=run=nginx  --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
```

**In a single command but using the endpoints information for the service `hello-world-service`**

```
kubectl get endpoints hello-world-service -o=jsonpath='{.subsets[*].addresses[*].ip}' | tr ' ' '\n' | kubectl get pods --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, "-o=name" is for displaying only pod name.

`kubectl get pods -o=name --all-namespaces | grep {service-name}`

Replace {service-name} with your service name

Comment: I don't think this works. The pod's name is prefixed by the `deployment` name, not the `service` name. In many tutorials, people tend to use the same name for both `deployment` and `service` (and a whole bunch of other stuff). That is handy but easy to mix up the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

List the services.

```
$ kubectl get services -o=wide
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP   11d   <none>
nginx-24     ClusterIP   10.111.9.176   <none>        808/TCP   15m   app=nginx-24
```

Note the `SELECTOR` `app=nginx-24`.

List the Pods.

```
$ kubectl get pods --selector=app=nginx-24
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-24-6dc9d8c7df-cp7rh   1/1     Running   0          97m
nginx-24-6dc9d8c7df-tzrwf   1/1     Running   0          97m
nginx-24-6dc9d8c7df-xnvgq   1/1     Running   0          97m
```